# Installed on separate hard drives, won't boot

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I just built a brand new computer, got Ubuntu running once before after install. `/, /boot`, and `/usr` on SSD, everything else on HDD.  Booting from live USB in order to install.

Like I said it was running once before but I didn't allocate enough space to `/tmp` and it kept giving me a warning. I attempted a fresh install and now after installation it will not boot.

Answer (score 0):

This also happen to me with my first SSD. In my case the problem appeard whenever I removed another hard drive that did not have ANYTHING to do to where I had installed the system. My only solution after a very weird problem (I even checked to see if grub was installed in the right place and even ran the grub installed again just to make sure.) was to do a fresh install. Just backup whatever needed backup and format that SSD. But this time, I did not connect any other hard drives, just the SSD all alone. At least that way I knew it would work.

This only happen to me with the SSD, with the rest of the Sata HDD it worked perfectly anytime I installed. Maybe, this can help you in some way. At least reinstalling grub or updating grub with the SDD alone (No other disks connected).

Comment: I've reinstalled probably two dozen times times now to no avail.  I partition it, installed grub to the root partition. Other than my first go around which removed windows nothing has worked.  I dont want the whole system on my ssd, just a fast boot and for programs/applications. I want to store all my pictures and such on the hard disk. I dont know what else to do.